# Typically under what circumstances will a SAS Pooled Workspace Server be launched?

Tags: sas

I am troubleshooting unauthorized access involving a launch credential for sas pooled workspace server. Hence I would like to know what are some of the common circumstances where a SAS pooled workspace server will be launched.

Answer (score 2):

SAS Web Report Studio and SAS BI Dashboard (webapplications) uses the Pooled Workspace server. They should be running under a common user (sassrv is default). There will be one running instance even though no-one uses it.
You can see the launch properties of the Pooled Workspaceserver in SAS Managent Console, under Server Manager>SASApp>SASApp-Logical Pooled Workspace Server>SASApp-Pooled Workspace Server>properties>Options>Advanced Options>Load Balancing

Comment: "There will be one running instance even though no-one uses it."
Does that mean if jboss is running there will be this running instance??

Comment: It is the object spawner that starts these SAS servers. You do not need JBoss running for a Pooled Workspace server to run. There are other clients that can run a Pooled WS, Information Map Studio is one example.